# log4j2 unable to create INFO level log

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have Log4j2 in my spring boot application and wish to log event into 2 log files. The UserService is unable to create the log for INFO level, but able to create for WARN level. Can anyone advise?

**Log4j2.xml**

```html
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="matchFile"
            fileName="${log-path}/match.log"
            immediateFlush="true">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="trace" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMAtch="accept" onMismatch="deny" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="confirmFile"
            fileName="${log-path}/confirm.log"
            immediateFlush="true">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="trace" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMAtch="accept" onMismatch="deny" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMAtch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
</Configuration>
```

**UserService.java**

```
public class UserService{
    Logger matchLogger = LogManager.getLogger("matchFile");
    Logger confirmLogger = LogManager.getLogger("confirmFile");
    
    public void log(){
        matchLogger.info("print info"); //not able to log this message
        confirmLogger.warn("print warn"); //able to log this message
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a wrong log level for your class ? Try to set com.mypackage.UserService to log level DEBUG

Comment: @sashok_bg I have typo in my script, can you please see again?

Comment: You have a typo `onMAtch` instead of `onMatch` in your config file. BTW: what you are looking for is the [`LevelMatchFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/LevelMatchFilter.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `<Loggers>` section in your config, where you declare the logger names to use in your code and attach appenders to them.
Also, the `ThresholdFilter` actually declares a level threshold, so that there's no need to specify a filter for each level.

Your config should look something like this:

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="matchFile"
            fileName="${log-pathmatchFile}/match.log"
            immediateFlush="true">
            <Filters>
                <!-- deny warn, error and fatal messages -->
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <!-- accept info, warn, error, fatal and deny debug, trace -->
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="accept" onMismatch="deny" />
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="confirmFile"
            fileName="${log-path}/confirm.log"
            immediateFlush="true">
            <Filters>
                <!-- deny error and fatal messages -->
                <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="deny" onMismatch="neutral" />
                <!-- accept warn, error, fatal and deny info, debug, trace -->
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="accept" onMismatch="deny" />
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    
    <Loggers>
        <!-- probably declare the root logger level and appenders:
            <Root level="...">
                <AppenderRef ref="..." />
            </Root>
        -->
        <Logger name="matchFile" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="matchFile" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="confirmFile" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="confirmFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```